# One Hot Encoding For Two Different Dataframe Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataframe with id variable as Toy and the different color schemes Toy comes in -

```
input_data = pd.DataFrame({'Toy': ['Toy1',  'Toy2', 'Toy3','Toy4'],
                      'Color1': ['Red', 'Orange',   '', 'Orange'],
                      'Color2': ['Red', '', 'Blue', 'Red']})
```

I want to one-hot encode the Color1 and Color2 variables, but have one single transformed variable (color name without any prefix)

```
output_data = pd.DataFrame({'Toy': ['Toy1', 'Toy2', 'Toy3', 'Toy4'],
            'Red': [1,  0,  0,  1],
            'Blue': [0, 0,  1,  0],
            'Orange': [0,   1,  0,  1]})
```

This seems to be a quick and easy output but I am not able to find a straight forward way of doing it. Any leads are really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) with joine values by `|`:

```
df = input_data.set_index('Toy').agg('|'.join, 1).str.get_dummies().reset_index()
print (df)
    Toy  Blue  Orange  Red
0  Toy1     0       0    1
1  Toy2     0       1    0
2  Toy3     1       0    0
3  Toy4     0       1    1
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a direct option. You could reshape and use `crosstab`:

```
d = input_data.replace('', float('nan')).melt(id_vars='Toy')
out = (pd.crosstab(d['Toy'],d['value'])
         .clip(upper=1)
         .reset_index().rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
       )
```

output:

```
    Toy  Blue  Orange  Red
0  Toy1     0       0    1
1  Toy2     0       1    0
2  Toy3     1       0    0
3  Toy4     0       1    1
```

Comment: @mozwayYou don't need dropna(), right? But it's still great.

Comment: `I don't think there is a direct option.` hmmm, are you sure?

Comment: @jezrael this is not direct, you need to drop the junk columns and aggregate

Comment: @mozway - hmmm, crosstab is not more complicated? Why should be preferd?

Comment: I didn't judge complexity ;) I just said my "*I don't think there is a direct option*" statement is fair. I wish there was an aggregation option in `get_dummies` but as of now there isn't :(

Comment: Yes, it's nice, although a native aggregation would still be preferred ;)